# Commons VFS and Java.net.URL - Adding support for "sftp://" protocol

Tags: java, linux, url, sftp, apache-commons-vfs

We're trying to use [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) to access something over SFTP. [It claims to support SFTP](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP), however we're getting a [MalformedURLException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) when it starts. Digging around I see that apache vfs is using [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). However the documentation tells me that it doesn't actually support `sftp://` URLs.

> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path :-
>
> ```
>     http, https, ftp, file, and jar
> ```
>
> Protocol handlers for additional protocols may also be available.

I'm using java 1.6.0 on Linux. How can I prevent `java.net.URL` from throwing a wobbly when it sees a `sftp://` URL? I need to keep using the Apache commons VFS library, which uses `java.net.URL`.

Comment: How are you creating the SFTP connection? Using Sftp client factory, or something else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See the list of [dependencies](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/download.html) that commons-vfs requires for sftp to work.  Once [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is in the classpath, your exception no longer happen.  Have a look at [Apache's Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/VfsFaq) for examples of connecting via sftp.

Comment: Installing JSch and including it in my jar file automagically fixed everything.

Comment: I added the dependency  <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId><artifactId>jsch</artifactId><version>0.1.51</version> to my pom.xml. But the problem still exist, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I've never used VFS before, but it looks like you'd need to (at least) [register](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs/impl/DefaultFileSystemManager.html#addProvider%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.FileProvider%29) an [SFTP `FileProvider`.](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs/provider/sftp/SftpFileProvider.html)  It looks like it requires something like:

```
DefaultFileSystemManager fsm = ... /* Create and configure your FSM. */
fsm.addProvider("sftp", new SftpFileProvider());
```

There is probably a way to do the same thing through [configuration file syntax.](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/api.html#Configuring_Commons_VFS)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this description](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjce.iaik.tugraz.at%2Fsic%2Fcontent%2Fdownload%2F837%2F6056%2Ffile%2FLDAP%2520for%2520the%2520Java%2520Net%2520URL%2520Framework%25201.pdf&ei=6nO7SvvoC8rz-Qax8IHSCw&rct=j&q=register+java.net.url+scheme&usg=AFQjCNHHGmXm2hj5msYH1-dNy1ONKqj1Cw&sig2=lgYBhKMWfpglMMD7m7WWsQ) about how to implement a new URL protocol handler (the document describes an LDAP kind-of-URL, but you should be able to generalize from that to your `sftp` scheme).

From the document:

> As you can see, the only difference
>   between the two examples is that we
>   have used an LDAP URL in the second
>   case. However, for running the LDAP
>   sample **you first will have to register
>   the LDAP protocol handler of IAIK-JCE
>   to tell the java.net URL framework
>   where to look for the LDAP supporting
>   classes** of IAIK-JCE:
>
> `System.getProperties().put("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",
>   "iaik.x509.net");`
>
> After having
>   registered the IAIK LDAP protocol
>   handler, an IAIK-JCE LdapURLConnection
>   object is returned when calling
>   url.openConnection for an LDAP URL.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

I use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to handle sftp and ssh. It won't help you preventing an exception from java.net.URL, but it will help you doing sftp stuff.

Comment: I need to use the Apache Commons VFS module. I don't want to rewrite core parts of that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your code is structured, you could remove the s before you give the string to the URL parsing method, set a flag, and if it validates, check that flag and put it back if it's set. It's ugly, but it'll provide a workaround.